# Superuser.com should better-identify as authentic Stack Exchange site

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hyperlinks, superuser

Suggestion: superuser.com should forward to superuser.stackexchange.com or something with stackexchange in the name, and should very-very-clearly be branded as part of the SE family.

I eventually figured out that it was, indeed, part of SE (right?! :) but, given all the fake-SE/SO copycat sites out there, it'd be nice to at least see stackexchange.com as part of the URL.

I love the whole SE family thing but, given that 99.44% of my usage is on Stack Overflow, when I go to a different member site, it'd be nice to know that I'm "in bounds" and haven't strayed to one of "those other guys" and am about to give them my account credentials, etc.

(Same suggestion for all the other members of the SE family that don't have SE.com in the URL.)

Comment: So do you favor `http://stackoverflow.stackexchange.com/`, too?

Comment: Related question: [Do Server Fault and Super User have to be separate from the Stack Overflow domain?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6239)

Comment: Ha!  Forgive me for not being an SE-family geek.  Am I wrong in thinking that SO is the most widely known/used of the bunch?  I get that it's possible to figure out that SU is part of the family -- what I'm suggesting is that it's not patently obvious to someone who doesn't know and, trying to be conscientious and not-patronize the copycat sites, I had to go fishing around in the fine-print to verify that I was, indeed, on a valid site.  Angry/sarcastic answers don't help -- I'm not stupid, although I admit extreme ignorance (since slightly reduced.)  Current is good; I'm suggesting better.

Comment: I thought SO SU and SF were trilogy sites, **predating** the existence of StackExchange???

Comment: @Adam: Yes, they are. `@Olie: I don't think anyone's calling you ignorant here, or complaining that you're not a geek. My comment wasn't intended to be angry or sarcastic.

Comment: Agreed, and what is SuperUser for??? Sub domain naming should make it easier to know when to use said site.
I tried to find an office 365 site and could not, so went to overflow, and was told to come here.
How is anyone meant to know that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a pretty good way to tell if you're on an SE site:

[image: Screenshot of the supercollider]

I've never seen a copy-cat site that tried to trick you into thinking you're on an SE site; generally they just clone content to get hits. In any case, they can't trick you into giving them your account credentials since SE sites only offer OpenIDs; if a site asks you for your password it's not an SE site

Comment: Nitpick: the domain proposal for Gaming specified that the domain would behave how the OP's proposing and redirect to gaming.stackexchange.com. Other sites with customer domains (AskDifferent.com and SeasonedAdvice.com) also redirect to SE subdomains (Apple and Cooking, respectively).

Comment: @AnnaLear Ah, yeah; that makes that part completely wrong. Edited

Answer (score 10):

Look for The genuine Stack Exchange™©® Logo in the upper left! All Stack Exchange (2.0) sites will have it.

[image]

It's also your global network inbox, so it's particularly important to click on and know about. You can't miss it, really.

Comment: So *this* is the crucial Meta question you come out of retirement to address???  :)

Comment: How did you get that strange, rigid-looking arrow?  It's almost as though it was not drawn freehand, but with some kind of automated drawing tool.

Comment: an face copycat can have the same html code on the site - so it is not save

Answer (score 6):

Um. It is right there in the footer of all SE sites:

[image]

It is also on the [master list](https://stackexchange.com/sites):

[image]

It has its own domain name as it was one of the [original trilogy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/).

Comment: "Um..." I don't read the tiny print in the footers of sites I go to for answers.  Similarly, I skip the ads.  :)   Yes, the information I'm requesting is available; I'm suggesting it could be more "in your face" as an aid to the ignorant-but-conscientious.  Own-domain is fine, and it should be a simple matter to forward.  Or more-obivously brand it.  Point being: it wasn't immediately clear, and it took me longer to verify than it did to find the answer to my question.  That's backwards.